# Markers of two different types in Googlemap JS

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working on a website for a small Estate agency.
I have a google map on the site showing all the available properties, with the properties data drawn from a Mysqli database via an XML call.  All this is working.
The client now wants the locations of the offices added.  These are not in the database, and so will require adding manually.
Is it possible to have two different 'var marker = new google.maps.Marker({' calls?  If so, I can't find where to position it outside of the loop that pulls each property data.
The working code is:

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.300000, 15.800000),
      zoom: 9
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

      downloadUrl('mapXMLcall.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var property = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('property');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(property, function(propertyElem) {
          var id = propertyElem.getAttribute('Idnumber');
          var name = propertyElem.getAttribute('Name');
          var price = propertyElem.getAttribute('Price');
          if (price == '999999') {var price = "POA"};
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(propertyElem.getAttribute('Lat')),
              parseFloat(propertyElem.getAttribute('Long')));

          var infowincontent = document.createElement('div');
          var strong = document.createElement('strong');
          strong.textContent = name
          infowincontent.appendChild(strong);
          infowincontent.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));

          var text = document.createElement('text');
          text.textContent = ' €' + price;
          infowincontent.appendChild(text);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            url: 'dbtest2.php?id=' + id
          });
          marker.addListener('mouseover', function() {
            infoWindow.setContent(infowincontent);
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
          });

              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            window.open("dbtest2.php?id=" + id, "_blank", "toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no, resizable=yes,top=100,left=100,width=920,height=900")
});
        });

      });
    }



  function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (request.readyState == 4) {
        request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
        callback(request, request.status);
      }
    };

    request.open('GET', url, true);
    request.send(null);
  }

  function doNothing() {}
</script>
```

Any advice gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add any "fixed" markers in your `initMap` function after you initialize the `map` variable (can be either before or after you call `downloadUrl`).

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.300000, 15.800000),
    zoom: 9
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  // add a fixed marker
  var anotherMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.300000, 15.800000),
  });

  downloadUrl('mapXMLcall.php', function(data) {
  // ...
  }
}
```